# ActiveRecord association between User and Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I have a User and a Event model. I want to be able to associate each event with multiple attending users, and then have another user who is also among the attendees, be labeled as the owner, such that I would be able to make calls like @event.users, to retrieve all attendees, @event.owner, to retrieve the owner and then also be able to call @user.events, to get the events the user is attending.

Would it be most optimal to create a third model called Events_Users that keeps track of the relationship between users and events by storing a user_id together with an event_id, or just update the existing Event model with a user_id, along with the owner_id?

Please, some concrete suggestions will be much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attendees, class_name: 'User' 
end
```

This way, you will have reference id to user in your `events` table (owner), and there will be join table for typical HABTM relationship for Users/Events (attendees for event).

Hope it helps!

***Update***
Here's associations for User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attended_events, class_name: 'Event'
end
```

***Update 2***
Here's the [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to Rails Guide to Associations. It will explain how to create appropriate tables and columns for these kinds of relationships.

Comment: wouldnt the User model also need to have defined associations?

Comment: Sure they need. I believe that was pretty obvious. I will update my answer in a sec.

Comment: Alright cool, I'm very new to Rails and still trying to get the hang of stuff

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I try to invoke the methods provided by the association, like @event.owner, nothing happens

Comment: You need to create appropriate tables for this. I will put a link  to guide into answer.